# showing colorful emoji both in pycharm editor and console

Tags: utf-8, console, pycharm, emoji

I am wondering if the pycharm 2018.2 is capable of showing the emojis in both IDE and Pyhton Console,
I have googled a lot and I did not find a useful answer, at the moment the
emojis are either not shown or they are rendered in monocolor.

I have set the editors encoding to UTF-8 and nothing has changed in the IDE, In addition I have tried different fonts and it did not work too, I am wondering if the IDE supports the colorful emojis or not!? If not what are the Font, Encoding, Plugins, .... required to activate the colorful emojis both in console and editor window.

Comment: As mentioned in blog [post](https://blog.jetbrains.com/idea/2016/12/intellij-idea-2017-1-eap-is-open/) on Windows and Linux emoji are rendered as monochrome characters